# Selenium Standalone Server in Docker - TimeoutException

Tags: linux, docker, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-hub

I tried to execute a `WebDriver 3.5` based test with `ChromeDriver 2.31` in a `Selenium Docker` container.
I used this command to start necessary container:

```
docker run -d -p 4444:4444 -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm selenium/standalone-chrome:3.5.3-astatine
```

I use `RemoteWebDriver` to execute testsuite on remote host. It fails with following log:

> org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: timeout   (Session info:
>   chrome=61.0.3163.79)   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.31.488763
>   , platform=Linux
>   4.10.0-33-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Build info: version: '3.5.2', revision: '10229a9', time:
>   '2017-08-21T17:29:55.15Z' Driver info:
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver Capabilities
>   [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false,
>   mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false,
>   chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.31.488763,
>   userDataDir=/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.IAkqFG},
>   takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal,
>   unhandledPromptBehavior=, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true,
>   hasTouchScreen=false, version=61.0.3163.79, platform=LINUX,
>   browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true,
>   acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true,
>   webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true,
>   javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, setWindowRect=true,
>   unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}]

I checked web panel on *http://:4444/wd/hub/static/resource/hub.html* and found, there is a Chrome session, but when I try to take a screenshot I get a blank screen. The test fails when trying to access to this site. 
The site uses invalid `SSL`, so `HTTPS` connection is insecure, but I use commands below to ignore certificate errors. It is working on local machine.

```
options.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
caps.setCapability (CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
```

Comment: Post the complete code you used to start the driver

Comment: @TarunLalwani : `DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome(); caps.setCapability (CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);          driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://ip-address:4444/wd/hub"),caps);`

Comment: And what's in the server's log (`docker logs <container name>`)?

Comment: @jannis : There isn't any new information. It seems it cannot be able to load a webpage.